# Ошибки при отправке данных в Redis

Tags: python, redis

Пытаюсь отправить данные в базу данных redis двумя способами

Первый:

```
DATA = {
    "Date": time_element.get_attribute('datetime'),
    "Name": file_name,
    "Short Hash": HASH[0][:8],
    "Full Hash": HASH[0],
    "Path": GIT_URL,
    "Download URL": GIT_URL.replace("blob", "raw") + "?inline=false"
}
REDIS.hmset(path, DATA)
```

Ошибка:

> DeprecationWarning: Redis.hmset() is deprecated. Use Redis.hset() instead.
> REDIS.hmset(path, DATA)
>
> > raise DataError("Invalid input of type: '%s'. Convert to a "
> > redis.exceptions.DataError: Invalid input of type: 'list'. Convert to a bytes, string, int or float first.

Второй:

```
REDIS.zadd(path, {
                time_element.get_attribute('datetime'): 1,
                file_name: 2,
                HASH[0][:8]: 3,
                HASH[0]: 4,
                GIT_URL: 5,
                GIT_URL.replace("blob", "raw") + "?inline=false": 6
            })
```

Ошибка:

> REDIS.zadd(path, {
>
> > TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Все переменные стринговые

Подскажите что я делаю не так
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что программист стреляет из печеньки

Ошибка была в листовой переменной file_name, а точнее в отсутствии скобочек file_name[0]